# Use a React Component in conjunction with Blocks

Tags: block-editor

I want to use a React Component which renders child items. The rendering of the children is bound to an array of objects of the component which holds the information for each item. So my idea is to use this component in conjunction with gutenberg blocks. The parent component is a block with the child items as the InnerBlocks. The React Components name is react-grid-layout (https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout). From users view: The user creates a block, ie "Draggable Grid" and can add Inner Blocks like Slider, Image, etc as Grid Items.

Currently I see no way how I can achieve that. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it's easy isn't it?

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried? It's probably not easy, but it's pretty much impossible without knowing what you've tried